# why mongoose subpopulation won't work in this?

Tags: node.js, meanjs, mongoose-populate

I'm encountering weird behavior with embedded docs and I don't know if I do something wrong or is it a bug.
I have defined my Exame Schema like this

```
var ExameSchema = new Schema({

_perguntas: [{
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Pergunta'
}],

created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
}
});
```

my Pergunta Schema is like this

```
var PerguntaSchema = new Schema({

created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
},
_exame: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Exame',
    required:'Um pergunta tem de estar associado a uma Exame'
},
_alternativas:[{
    type:Schema.ObjectId,
    ref:'Alternativa'
}]
```

});

and my Alternativa schema like this

```
var AlternativaSchema = new Schema({
conteudo: {
    type: String,
    default: '',
    //required: 'Please fill Alternativa conteudo',
    trim: true
},
created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
},
pergunta: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Pergunta'
}
```

});

calling 
`Exame.find().populate('_perguntas')` will populate the exame object with perguntas objects in the array but calling `Exame.find().populate('_perguntas').populate('_alternativas');` or `Exame.find().populate('_perguntas').populate('_perguntas._alternativas');` as described in the official documentation will not sub-populate the _perguntas object with alternativas documents, instead it returns an array of objectId's.
could somebody please tell-me where i got it wrong??